# Swap using only two variables not working

Tags: c, quicksort

I was writing a C code for quick sort but something went wrong. After some debugging i finally found where my code was going wrong.
When i replaced

```
     {
a[lp]+=a[ub];
a[ub]=a[lp]-a[ub];
a[lp]=a[lp]-a[ub];
}
```

with

```
  {
tmp=a[lp];
a[lp]=a[ub];
a[ub]=tmp;
}
```

my code started working.
I am Curious to know why my initial implementation of swapping didn't work?
Can anyone help me?

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #define swap(a,b) (a)=(a)+(b);b=(a)-(b);(a)=(a)-(b);
    int a[]={7,1,5,2,3};
    int partition(int lb,int ub)
    {
    int k,hp,lp;
    k=a[ub];
    lp=lb-1;
    for(hp=lb;hp<ub;hp++)
    {
    if(a[hp]<k)
    {
    lp++;
    int tmp=a[lp];
    a[lp]=a[hp];
    a[hp]=tmp;
    }
    }
    lp++;
    a[lp]+=a[ub];
    a[ub]=a[lp]-a[ub];
    a[lp]=a[lp]-a[ub];
    return lp;
    }
    void quicksort(int lb,int ub)
    {
    if(lb<ub)
    {
    int pos=partition(lb,ub);
    quicksort(lb,pos-1);
    quicksort(pos+1,ub);
    }
    }
    int main()
    {
    quicksort(0,4); 
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)printf("%d ",a[i]);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the problem? [Seems fine to me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/35084bd05c33eec5). Perhaps the issue lies elsewhere in your algorithm.

Comment: Like many such hacks, your swap fails if the two variables are the same. It's almost invariably better to use straightforward code.

Comment: Just do it idiomatically and let the compiler optimize it.

Comment: Format your code before posting it. It will be much more readable for everybody you included.

Comment: Don't try to do things like that, it may overflow and you'll get something unexpected. Just use simple assignments, most compilers are smart enough to optimize it

Comment: @Luu vinh- yeah, the question was just for curiosity purpose, i usually prefer simpler and direct code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to consider what happens when lp == ub (ie. you are being asked to swap an element with itself).

Change it to this:

```
if (lp != ub) {
    a[lp]+=a[ub];
    a[ub]=a[lp]-a[ub];
    a[lp]=a[lp]-a[ub];
}
```

Example: http://ideone.com/AS1Dgf